# How can I determine if a component returns nothing dynamically?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, handlebars.js

I have a ember component that is accessing a database and returning the results in a datatable type UI component.  I would like to be able to use "N/A" when the result of the component is null or nothing.

For example, I have:

```
{{each bar in foobars}}
  <td class="classyTD">
    {{getBars bar=bar}}
  </td>
{{/each}}
```

This works great when I have data, but returns nothing when I don't have data.  The designers would prefer an "N/A".  Modifying the database isn't an option and while modifying the component `getBars` is an option, it will be extremely painful.

Is there a method/way to handle this after the execution of the component?  If not, or if it's a terrible idea -  I'll suffer through changing the component, I trust the community's opinion.

Comment: Use an `if` in the getBars template to display N/A if bar is empty or null. Is that the question you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should do this inside the component template. You can give the N/A string as a parameter, if that's of any help: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lemabekuwi/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Or you could change the component that it indicates emptiness through a class and use some css magic: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/duqazahegi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: As suggested, I've added logic inside the component template - not sure why this didn't occur to me, but thank you all for the easy fixes!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit logic in the handlebars you can have the following in the component js file:

```
({
  setBar: (function() {
    if (!this.get('bar')) {
      return this.set('bar', 'N/A');
    }
  }).observes('bar')
});
```